# Beamer Metropolis progress bar: Use page number instead of frame number

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

In Beamer's `metropolis` theme, is it possible to set the progress bar so that it tracks progress using page numbers instead of frame numbers? In the following example, the progress bar doesn't change because there's just one frame. However, I'd like the progress bar to update as the page updates with each overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I found in the [`metropolis` documentation](https://tug.org/docs/latex/beamertheme-metropolis/metropolistheme.pdf) a snippet that controls the progress bar setting:

```
\setbeamertemplate{progress bar in head/foot}{
  \nointerlineskip
  \setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot}{%
    \paperwidth * \ratio{\insertframenumber pt}{\inserttotalframenumber pt}%
  }%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{progress bar in head/foot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[bg] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth, \metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth); 
    \fill[fg] (0,0) rectangle (\metropolis@progressinheadfoot, \metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

It would seem natural to replace `\insertframenumber` with `\insertpagenumber` and `\inserttotalframenumber` with `\inserttotalpagenumber`. However, I couldn't find in the [Beamer documentation](http://websites.uwlax.edu/ekim/resources/beameruserguide.pdf) any macro that records the total page number. I also got an error when trying to use `\pageref{LastPage}` with the `lastpage` package.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the number from `\pageref{}` cannot be used for calculations. One has to use `\getpagerefnumber{}`. I also include a conditional to catch the `! Arithmetic overflow` error when the `LastPage` label is initially undefined.

Full working code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlastpagenum{
  \@ifundefined{r@LastPage}{1}{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
}
\setbeamertemplate{progress bar in head/foot}{
  \nointerlineskip
  \setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot}{%
    \paperwidth * \ratio{\insertpagenumber pt}{\insertlastpagenum pt}%
  }%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{progress bar in head/foot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[bg] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth, \metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth); 
    \fill[fg] (0,0) rectangle (\metropolis@progressinheadfoot, \metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item \item Some item\label<.->{pp} 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```